# How to validate with Zod into a loop fields?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form, zod

I'm currently facing an issue with my Astro/React web app. I'm building a form using ShadcnUI's form, which involves the integration of Zod and React Hook Form.

I initialize the form in a parent component and pass the form.control to child components that contain portions of the form. Here's the relevant part of the parent component:

```
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import * as z from "zod"

export default function Booking(props: BookingModalProps) {
const { open, setOpen, serviceId } = props;
const [extras, setExtras] = useState<ExtrasProps[]>([]);
const responseService = await axios.get(`${ameliaURL}${urlSuffixService}`, {
  headers: headers,
  signal: signal,
});
setExtras(responseService.data.data.service.extras)

const formSchema = z.object({
nom: z.string().min(2).max(50),
extras: z.object(
  extras.reduce((acc, option) => {
    acc[option.name] = z.object({
      enabled: z.boolean(),
      quantity: z.number().refine(value => value >= 0 && value <= option.maxQuantity, {
        message: `La quantité doit être comprise entre 0 et ${option.maxQuantity}.`
      }),
    });
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, z.ZodObject<{
    enabled: boolean;
    quantity: number;
  }>>)
),
});

 const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
   resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
   defaultValues: {
     // ... vos valeurs par défaut ici ...
   },
 });

 function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
   // Do something with the form values.
   // ✅ This will be type-safe and validated.
   console.log(values);
 }

return (

<Form {...form}>
  <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        <Options
          options={extras}
          control={form.control}
        />
        <ProfileForm
          control={form.control}
        />
    <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
  </form>
 </Form>

 )

}
```

And here's the child component, where I have a switch for each iteration. If the switch is active, it opens a new number field.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import type { ExtrasProps } from '../types/ServiceTypes'

import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormDescription,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { Switch } from "@/components/ui/switch"
import { Input } from '../ui/input';

interface OptionsProps {
    options: ExtrasProps[];
    control: any;
}
export default function Options(props: OptionsProps) {
    const { options, control } = props
    const handleOptionChange = (optionId: string) => {
      // Mise à jour de l'array selectedOptions en fonction de l'optionId
      const updatedOptions = selectedOptions.includes(optionId)
        ? selectedOptions.filter((id) => id !== optionId)
        : [...selectedOptions, optionId];
      setSelectedOptions(updatedOptions);
    };

    console.log("selec",selectedOptions)
    return (
        <>
            {options && options.map((option) => (
                <div key={option.id}>
                    <FormField
                        control={control}
                        name={`${option.name}-${option.id}`}
                        render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between rounded-lg border p-4">
                                <div className="space-y-0.5 max-w-sm">
                                    <FormLabel className="text-base">
                                        {option.name}
                                    </FormLabel>
                                    <FormDescription>
                                    {option.description} + {option.price}€
                                    </FormDescription>
                                </div>
                                <FormControl>
                                    <Switch
                                        checked={field.value}
                                        onCheckedChange={(checked) => {
                                            field.onChange(checked);
                                            handleOptionChange(option.id);
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </FormControl>
                            </FormItem>
                        )}
                    />
                    {selectedOptions.includes(option.id) && (
                        <FormField
                            control={control}
                            name={option.name}
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <FormItem>
                                    <FormLabel>Quantité</FormLabel>
                                    <FormControl>
                                        <Input type='number' step={1} min={0} max={option.maxQuantity} {...field} />
                                    </FormControl>
                                    <FormMessage />
                                </FormItem>
                            )}
                        />
                    )}
                </div>

            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

My difficulty lies in how to manage validation with Zod and React Hook Form on dynamic fields like this. I've tried several things, including the following form schema:

```
  const formSchema = z.object({
    nom: z.string().min(2).max(50),
    extras: z.object(
      extras.reduce((acc, option) => {
        acc[option.name] = z.object({
          enabled: z.boolean(),
          quantity: z.number().refine(value => value >= 0 && value <= option.maxQuantity, {
            message: `La quantité doit être comprise entre 0 et ${option.maxQuantity}.`
          }),
        });
        return acc;
      }, {} as Record<string, z.ZodObject<{
        enabled: boolean;
        quantity: number;
      }>>)
    ),
  });
```

But everything has failed. If anyone has an idea...